# IAM policy to startinstance in specific vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, identity-management, aws-iam-policy

Can anyone help me how to write the IAM policy for starting the instances which are in a specific vpc (some specific vpc-id)

I couldn't find the vpc specific conditions while mentioning resource type as instance.( **Problem is that I can't use tags as the users themselves create instance and should able to start and stop on their own **)

Comment: No VPC condition for StartInstances. You can find the full list of available conditions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html. My recommendation would be to separate your VPCs into different accounts, which is generally AWS's recommendation anyways.

Comment: You might want to consider enforcing a tagging strategy, then you can potentially use tags as conditions.